# Error when writting image from python to Excel

Tags: python, excel, image, numpy, openpyxl

I am trying to run this code:

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Output_Report_v16.xlsm',read_only=False,keep_vba=True)
sheets=wb.sheetnames
sheet_InputData_Overview=wb [sheets[7]]

img=openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('Eink_Liq.png')
sheet_InputData_Overview.add_image(ws.cell(2,28))

wb.save('Output_Report_v16.xlsm')
```

When python runs the last line of code this error arises:

'Cell' object has no attribute '_id'

The excel file contains VBA which should not be changed or deleted.

Do you have any idea what may be wrong with this code?

Comment: Why have you used `add_image(ws.cell(2, 28)`? This won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to be a few issues with your code but the problem is appying the image.
You created the img object but never use it.
ws.cell references an object not defined

```
...
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Output_Report_v16.xlsm',read_only=False,keep_vba=True)
sheets=wb.sheetnames
sheet_InputData_Overview=wb [sheets[7]]

img=openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('Eink_Liq.png')

### This line is wrong and references 'ws' object not defined
# sheet_InputData_Overview.add_image(ws.cell(2,28))

### Set the position for the image in the sheet
img.anchor = sheet_InputData_Overview.cell(row=2, column=28).coordinate
### Add the image 'img' to the sheet
sheet_InputData_Overview.add_image(img)


wb.save('Output_Report_v16.xlsm')
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix after looking at the attributes of Cell. Try this:

```
ws[cell].style = Style(font=Font(color=Color(colors.RED)))
```

Comment: after which line of code shall I write your code? When writing your line of code, the following error arises: name 'Style' is not defined

Comment: I'm not sure how this line fixes the issue. The problem is trying to save the wb where a sheet has an incorrect image added; **add_image(ws.cell(2,28))** is not an image.